# Why the symmetric property doesn't fit to the question: How many even numbers with $9 $ different digits (without zero) the digit $1 $ is before $2 $?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question contains $\ 2$ sections :

1. How many numbers with $\ 9 $ different digits (not include zero) the digit $1$ is before $2$?
2. How many $even$ numbers with $9$ different digits (not include zero) the digit $1$ is before $2$?

I've calculated the first section and made sure that my answer is correct $36 * 7!$

I thought that because we know that the right-most digit cannot be $1$, it can only be $2-9$, so we have the same number of right-most digits for $even$ numbers $(2,4,6,8)$ and for $odd$ numbers $(3,5,7,9)$.
Hence, we can use the symmetric property so the answer is $18 * 7! $  but, it seems incorrect, where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly there are the same number of numbers ending in any given digit without the restriction of $1$ being before $2$.

The issue is as follows: looking at numbers ending $3,5,7,9$, half of them have the property that you want ($1$ before $2$). The same is true of numbers ending $4,6,8$, but *all* of the numbers ending in $2$ have the required property. So the ratio of odd to even numbers with this property is $4:5$.

Answer (score 1):

Argument from symmetry is a powerful tool when it comes to problems involving combinatorics or probability. But before we use it, we must ensure the situation actually is symmetric in the relevant context.

Even without going into the specifics (which *Especially Lime* has explained well in their answer), there is a clear red flag as to why symmetry may not be applicable here.

You were right in assuming that the rightmost digit could only be one of the eight digits from $2-9$. However, these eight digits don't share the same attributes. $2$ is distinct in that it cannot appear before $1$.

And there goes symmetry out of the window.